# Is FLOPS included in the number of instructions given by perf_event?

Tags: perf, flops

I have a program which uses *perf_event.h* to calculate the [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_cycle) of a specific running process. I read the *INSTRUCTIONS* counter and the *CPU_CYCLES* counter to do so.

My question is about the value returned by the *INSTRUCTIONS* counter. Does it contain the floating-point operations? If not, how can I get this value?

> **Note:** I'm talking about *perf_event.h* but, yes, I'm also talking about `perf` and the counters I mentioned are the ones you can find with the command `perf list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Intel architectures (I guess it's the same for others), yes it contains floating-point instructions . If you look at `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_intel.c` in kernel code. You will see that the `instructions` event is mapped to `0x00c0`:

```
 [PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS]     = 0x00c0
```

The Intel Software Developer Manual Chapter 19.1 says that this event counts `Instruction retired`, that is all instructions completed that were "proven" as indeed needed by flow (Modern processors execute much more instructions that the program flow needs. This is called "speculative execution", see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/311170))

Comment: I didn't know the *Intel Software Developer Manual*. Now, this is my bible for a better understanding of my Intel CPU and its interpretation by my Linux OS. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this document is a must have for anyone wanting to understand its Linux OS running on top of Intel processor. Nevertheless it's quite difficult to read and very dense.